# Asp.net yellow code  <% vs Explicit asp control 

Tags: asp.net

I have a literal in my aspx called xxx.

Now lets go into the JS world.

I always used  :

```
   alert('audit.aspx?claim_id=<%= xxx.Text%>');
```

But Ive seen a code like this :

```
     alert('audit.aspx?claim_id=<asp:Literal id="xxx" runat="server" />');
```

This is also working.

Can I conclude that the `<asp:Literal` is equal to   `<%=`   syntax ?

I know that he is a RUNAT server Item...

but again - I want to see the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `asp:Literal` control simply outputs the value of its `Text` property when the page is rendered. That's why the resulting JavaScript looks the same when viewed by the client. But the two are not the same, no.

`<%= xxx.Text %>` explicitly reads the value of this text property and writes it out. The `Literal` control will be elsewhere on the page, where its `Text` property will also be written out.

Placing the `asp:Literal` control within your JavaScript relies on the rendering of this control to place the value there, and because this is its location within your page, there's no need to have the same content rendered elsewhere.

However, neither taken in isolation seems an appropriate use of this control to my mind. If you have simple text you want written out, then expose it as a property of your `Page`-derived code-behind class.

Comment: That wasnt my question I know what literal is.  I asked when it comes to interperate the strings - and he sees <asp:Literal inside a string without yellow code as  <%  - so how does he behave ?

Comment: The JavaScript sees neither. Both forms are rendered by the server-side code as the Text property value of the Literal control.

Answer (score 0):

The Literal class is basically a placeholder for text, but it also exposes events which you can hook into for greater control.

Have a look at the API here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx